# I can't see store and store view in store menu in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

[image]

**My store and storeview both and not showing in window.**

**Please help**

Comment: Have you created them (top right links)?

Comment: no i tried but got stucked and on internet most of the blogs are writing code in app/code/Vender/Module/web so I confused there.

Comment: You need to create at least one store and one store view to get your shop running.

Comment: its done bro it was some other kind of issue and I was solved by minor changes in the database and reindexing. thanks anyway for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindex